# Interpreting spline results from scam

Tags: r, interpretation, generalized-additive-model, splines, mgcv

I would like to know how can I be able to interpret the results from fitting splines with the `scam` package.

My data points are taken from the `chileancredit` dataset available in the package `smbinning`.

Here are my `x` and `y` data points:

```
library("scam")
library("zoo")
data(chileancredit, package = "smbinning")
chilean_clean <- na.omit(chileancredit)
x <- unique(sort(chilean_clean$TOB[1000:length(chilean_clean$TOB)]))
y_mav <- rollmean(chilean_clean$FlagGB, k = 1000)
y <- y_mav[(length(y_mav)-length(x)+1):length(y_mav)]
```

`y` is the moving average of a binary target variable.

With the `scam` function I could fit a convex spline to my datapoints (I specified 5 parameters in total):

```
spline_fit <- scam(y~ s(x,k=5,bs="cx",m=2),
                   family=gaussian(link="identity"), 
                   data=as.data.frame(x=x,y=y))
```

However, the five coefficients I could get from `scam`, I'm having trouble interpreting them:

```
(Intercept)      s(x).1      s(x).2      s(x).3      s(x).4 
   0.9275358  -4.3564887  -4.8378830  -4.8522646  -4.8950387
```

The first term is the intercept, however I've lookup up in the results of `scam` for knots or cuts - seems like there is none. I don't know how I could interpret the smoothing parameters without the knots. Anyone has any idea? Thanks.

Comment: The `s(x).i` terms are the penalised regression coefficients for the 4 basis functions in the model, they're not smoothness parameters. You code isn't working for me; I get an error that the `x` and `y` lengths differ. Can you run your code in a clean session and update as needed? Then I'll take a closer look.

Comment: @GavinSimpson thank you I fixed the code and now it should be reproducible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after reading this **Wood S.N. (2006) Generalized Additive Models: An Introduction with R**, the coefficients from the output are difficult in giving a valid interpretation. But with `predict.gam` from package `mgcv` they can be directly applied in prediction.