# Shape preserving spline regression

Tags: regression, references, nonlinear-regression, splines, interpolation

There are shape-preserving, preserving especially positivity, monotonicity or convexity, spline interpolations such as described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_cubic_interpolation) and [here](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/46f7/79b0915451a2f251fdbc93dc6a8e19d7e998.pdf?_ga=2.154174960.994436643.1576887847-929173290.1555963142). Are there similar shape-preserving spline regression methods? I suppose I can modify the methodology prescribed in the interpolation papers to regression. However, it would be great if there are already existing methods in place. References would be most welcome.

Comment: Certainly, some related posts: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/206073/looking-for-function-to-fit-sigmoid-like-curve/316446#316446, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/276487/interpreting-spline-results-from-scam, https://researchportal.bath.ac.uk/en/studentTheses/additive-models-with-shape-constraints

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen: Excellent, especially the Ph.D. thesis in the last reference. Thank you.